# Order of radio button options and default option

Tags: lists, radio-buttons, ordering

I am currently putting a form together for subscribing to email notifications. One of the options called 'Frequency' allows the user to select how frequently they want to receive notifications. At the moment, we are debating the ordering of the frequency options.

My query is whether or not we should be ordering the four options based on the amount of time (i.e. Every 4 hours, Every 12 hours, Daily, Custom (Custom allows them to select Monday-Sunday which would be displayed in checkboxes below 'Custom' if it is selected only)), or if we should order by most frequently used (daily being the most frequently used option which is why it must be the default option selected).

**Note**: These options are set in stone, and the default option selected **must** be 'Daily' (which is the most popular option with our users.

Below are the two options. Feedback would be much appreciated.

[image: Ordered by most frequently used by user]

[image: Ordered by highest to lowest frequency]

Answer (score 1):

best option for me would be:
daily
every 12 h
every 4 h
custom

because: default option should stay at the top, then i would apply a logical ordering of decrease, considering "daily" means 24 h, then "12 h", "4 h". "custom" at the end.bye!

Answer (score 0):

You should list the options in a logical order, such as most likely or convenient option to be selected, to least. Or from simplest operation to most complex, or least risk to most. Since you need a default for radio buttons, it makes most sense to tick option 1, and if that is the most likely option, you are making great use of the defaulting principle as well.

In your case, daily as the first option and the default sounds like a more desirable option as it can feel less spammy for your users. Anyone who wants a more frequent newsletter can change the setting. So essentially, your first design.

Answer (score 0):

You show in increasing order of value .

- 4h
- 12h
- Daily
- Custom

> the order of default option doesnt matter.because you may want to
>   change the default option latter.